# Restore Windows Phone backup to emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, restore

Not sure if this is the correct forum or website, but I am desperate :) I would like to restore a backup of my windows phone to the WP emulator but cannot get it to work. The phone is supposed to prompt you for a restore when you set it up the first time, but the emulator does not.

Comment: Is there a reason *why* you're trying to do this - we might still be able to help you solve your original problem

Comment: I wanted to confirm if the contacts are included int he backup, but have found that they are not. Thanks for the reply

Comment: In which case, that's not a programmign question per se; but see also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1142/106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator doesn't support this scenario